Geometry nodes: Face Corner to Face domain (Rounded)
I want to convert Face Corner Selection to Face Selection but Rounded, so Evaluate on domain node not suitable for my task. Can you propose the simpliest method to do this convertion?


To round up, evaluate on domain, but with float type:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
The reason it works is:

Boolean socket implicitly converts false values to $0$, and true to $1$ when connected to a float socket.
Domain interpolation takes the average of all connected elements.
Float to Boolean implicitly converts by making all positive values true, otherwise false.

So the "Evaluate on Domain" node above does this behind the scenes:

Imgur mirror
And because the average of all zero-or-one values will only ever be zero if all the values were zero, you get the rounding up behavior.
